# Multiple SWF accessing user Camera

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, camera, flash

I have a html page that have 2 swf files trying to access the user camera.
My problem is that both swf files, when loaded through the flash player are requesting access to the camera.

Is it possible to make the request just once?

How can I check if the access is already granted to one of the files avoiding the user to repeat the granted access to the first swf ?

Or is it possible to make the 2nd swf use the camera object already in the 1st swf ? With JS or sharing the camera object?

Comment: Do you try with LocalConnection API? I am not sure but try with local connection API for communication between two swf file and try to get Camera Object to display...

Comment: Can you give me some brife idea about your application? is there any Media Server usage or not?